# Create a file for each defined block with puppet

Tags: puppet

I have a running manifest, where I create a folder and a file from a setting (exerpt):

```
define ffnord::mesh(
  $mesh_if_id = "low",
  $mesh_mtu_low = 1280,
  $fastd_low_port = 11280, # fastd port
) {
  ffnord::fastd { "fastd_${mesh_code}":
    mesh_if_id => $mesh_if_id,
    mesh_mtu_low  => $mesh_mtu_low,
    fastd_low_port   => $fastd_low_port,
  }
}
```

and

```
define ffnord::fastd( $mesh_if_id
                     , $mesh_code
                     , $mesh_mtu_low = 1280
                     , $fastd_low_port
                     ) {

  file {
    "/etc/fastd/${mesh_code}-mesh-low-vpn/":
      ensure =>directory,
             require => Package[ffnord::resources::fastd];
    "/etc/fastd/${mesh_code}-mesh-low-vpn/fastd.conf":
      ensure => file,
             notify => Service[ffnord::resources::fastd],
             content => template('ffnord/etc/fastd/fastd-low.conf.erb');
  } 
}
```

How can I define a variable amount of those configs:

```
  $mesh_if_id = "low",
  $mesh_mtu_low = 1280,
  $fastd_low_port = 11280, # fastd port

  $mesh_if_id = "something",
  $mesh_mtu_low = 12345,
  $fastd_low_port = 112345, # fastd port
  ...
```

and loop through those blocks to create a folder and file inside `ffnord/etc/fastd/` for each block automatically?

(I want to solve this problem: https://github.com/ffnord/ffnord-puppet-gateway/pull/116#issuecomment-100619610 )

Comment: I must be missing something: can't you just declare multiple meshes?

Comment: Only multiple instances for the fastd Daemon. So you can choose which you want to connect to. But that's not the question here

Answer (score 2):

In Puppet 3.x there is no "looping", but there are a few tricks. You can pass a Hash of data that represents *N* number of ffnord::fastd instances:

```
define define ffnord::mesh($fastd_hash) {
  create_resources('ffnord::fastd', $fastd_hash)
}

define ffnord::fastd($mesh_code, $fastd_low_port, $mesh_mtu_low = 1280) {
  file {
    "/etc/fastd/${mesh_code}-mesh-low-vpn/":
      ensure =>directory,
             require => Package[ffnord::resources::fastd];
    "/etc/fastd/${mesh_code}-mesh-low-vpn/fastd.conf":
      ensure => file,
             notify => Service[ffnord::resources::fastd],
             content => template('ffnord/etc/fastd/fastd-low.conf.erb');
  } 
}

$hash_of_fastds = {
  "low_id" => {
    mesh_code      => 'low,
    mesh_mtu_low   => 1280,
    fastd_low_port => 11280,
  },
  "some_id" => {
    mesh_code      => 'something',
    mesh_mtu_low   => 12345,
    fastd_low_port => 112345,
  },
}

ffnord::mesh { 'foo': fastd_hash => $hash_of_fastds, }
```

**Note** I've modified *define ffnord::fastd* slightly, where you had a $mesh_if_id parameter I've turned this into the $namevar of *ffnord::fastd*.

The first level of *$hash_of_fastds* translates to the names of the *ffnord::fastd* instances, the second level of the hash are the parameters for each *ffnord::fastd*.

See the [documentation on the create_resources function](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/function.html#createresources) for more information.

In Puppet 4 you could use the *each* function to achieve a similar result.

Comment: Good thinking. But question to the OP: Are you sure the `define ffnord::fastd` should be thus empowered? It looks to me as though it might make more sense for the user to create multiple instances of this define in the first place.

Comment: We want to define a hash of interfaces with port, name and MTU, that all will be created as config files. This definition will be extracted and put in a site-file for each community. But they all will use the same puppet scripts

Comment: Felix is right, if the above definitions are the entirety of your requirements, there's no **need** to pass a hash of data into ffnord::mesh in order to create ffnord::fastd. Your ffnord::fastd definition takes all of the arguments needed to create itself and doesn't require any information from an enclosing ffnord::mesh defined type. The two types are at the moment, independent from a Puppet point of view.

Comment: @LukeBigum: no the above definition is only an exerpt. the definition of `ffnord::fastd` is some pages long

Comment: I see, does my original example help at all then?